# Python Label image doesn't exist but os.path says it does

Tags: python, tkinter, label

Here is the code that is driving me crazy:

```
from tkinter import*
import os.path
class About:
    def __init__(self):
        font1='tahoma 12'
        win=Tk()
        print(os.path.isfile('logo.gif'))#It returns true
        Label(win,image="logo.gif").pack()                
About()
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Label(win,image="logo.gif").pack()
```

The `image` parameter won't accept a filename. According to [this](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm) tutorial, "the value should be a PhotoImage, BitmapImage, or a compatible object." It goes on to discuss the `PhotoImage` class, which you should use instead.

> You can use the label to display PhotoImage and BitmapImage objects. When doing this, make sure you keep a reference to the image object, to prevent it from being garbage collected by Python’s memory allocator. You can use a global variable or an instance attribute, or easier, just add an attribute to the widget instance:

```
photo = PhotoImage(file="icon.gif")
w = Label(parent, image=photo)
w.photo = photo
w.pack()
```